# Django | Serializer for Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I got two models ***Book*** and ***Author*** implemented like this:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In addition to this I got the following Serializers:

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)

class BookSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = AuthorSerializer()
```

Serializing objects works without any problems.

#### Now I got the following situation:

Author's:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Josh Robert |
| 2 | J. R. R. Tolkien |
| 3 | Mike Towers |

I get a **POST** request to an API endpoint on my server

> http://127.0..0.1:8000/api/book

looking like this:

```
payload = {
'name': 'Lord of the rings',
'author': 2
}
```

How can I use my Serializers to create a new Book with the given name and link it with the author no. 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `user_id` field for writing in the `BookSerializer`.
You don't need to set the `id` field by the way. Django will automatically deal with the `id` field if you derive from the `serializers.ModelSerializer`.

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        Model = Author

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = AuthorSerializer(read_only = True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'author', 'author_id',)
        Model = Book
```

And in frontend, payload should be

```
{
    'name': 'Lord of the rings',
    'author_id': 2
}
```